# How to wrap multiple strings into single string in postman to call spring boot rest API Get request

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

can anyone help me how can I wrap multiple strings into a single string in postman and call spring boot rest API.

from postman I am calling my rest API via GET request

```
localhost:8084/restapi/v1?searchRequest= {"userId":"value1","userGroup":"value2","staus":"value2"}
```

here inside searchRequest I would like to wrap "userId","userGroup" and "status" with values to call my spring boot rest API Get request. and in my service class I am trying to covert this string to DTO but it is not converting, here is my code in the controller, service layer, util class

```
    Controller:


    @Autowired
        private UserUtility userUtility;

        @GetMapping(path = "/restapi/v1", consumes = "text/plain")
            public UserInfoDetails searchUserDetails(@RequestParam String searchRequest) {

                UserInfoDetails userInfoDetails = new UserInfoDetails();
                try {
                    userUtility.searchUserDetails(searchRequest);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
                return userInfoDetails;
            }

    Util class

@Autowired

    private ModelMapper mapper;

    public UserInfoDetails searchUserDetails(String searchRequest) {

        UserInfoDetails userInfoDetails = new UserInfoDetails ();

        try {
        SearchRequest    SearchRequest =mapper.map(searchRequest, SearchRequest.class);
            //some business logic and assign the details to     userInfoDetails 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return userInfoDetails ;

    }

    Search Request class

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    public class SearchRequest {

        private String userId;

        private String userGroup;

        private String status;

    }
```

i tried multiple ways but could not succeed, any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: can you show me your SearchRequest class

Comment: Can also add the controller code and the complete service to have a better understanding of the code? I think you should also change the api name

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to pass all the parameters as `RequestParam` and them bind them to object directly

**Request :**

```
localhost:8084/restapi/v1?userId=value1,userGroup=value2,staus=value3
```

**POJO :**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class SearchRequest {

    private String userId;

    private String userGroup;

    private String status;

}
```

**Controller :**

```
@GetMapping(path = "/restapi/v1", consumes = "text/plain")
        public UserInfoDetails searchUserDetails(SearchRequest searchRequest){

            //some code
        }
```

Comment: No sir,  my expectation is if the request parameters grows it does not look good to append in url